# AppCompat v7 error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-appcompat

Help me to fix error when I put ndroid-support-v7-appcompat

I have setup dependencies in to the eclipse workplace.(Running on adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702)

```
target=android-19
android.library.reference.1=../../android-support-v7-appcompat
android.library.reference.2=../../google-play-services_lib
android.library.reference.3=../LibSlideMenu-master/libslidemenu
```

**appcompat v7 property
target=android-21
android.library=true**

**google playservice lib 
target=android-21
android.library=true**

**lib slide menu 
target=android-17
android.library=true**

```
[2015-05-13 16:15:39 - CabBookingHome] C:\ECLIPSE 19\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
[2015-05-13 16:15:39 - CabBookingHome] 
[2015-05-13 16:15:39 - CabBookingHome] C:\ECLIPSE 19\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:79: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
[2015-05-13 16:15:39 - CabBookingHome] 
[2015-05-13 16:15:39 - CabBookingHome] C:\ECLIPSE 19\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:84: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
[2015-05-13 16:15:39 - CabBookingHome] 
[2015-05-13 16:15:39 - CabBookingHome] C:\ECLIPSE 19\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:25: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2015-05-13 16:15:39 - CabBookingHome] 
[2015-05-13 16:15:39 - CabBookingHome] C:\ECLIPSE 19\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:29: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2015-05-13 16:15:39 - CabBookingHome] 
[2015-05-13 16:15:39 - CabBookingHome] C:\ECLIPSE 19\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:33: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2015-05-13 16:15:39 - CabBookingHome] 
[2015-05-13 16:15:39 - CabBookingHome] C:\ECLIPSE 19\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:37: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2015-05-13 16:15:39 - CabBookingHome] 
[2015-05-13 16:15:39 - CabBookingHome] C:\ECLIPSE 19\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:41: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2015-05-13 16:15:39 - CabBookingHome] 
[2015-05-13 16:15:39 - CabBookingHome] C:\ECLIPSE 19\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:65: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
[2015-05-13 16:15:39 - CabBookingHome] 
[2015-05-13 16:15:39 - CabBookingHome] C:\ECLIPSE 19\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:69: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
[2015-05-13 16:15:39 - CabBookingHome]
```

Comment: You have to use api 21 to compile the appCompat v21

Comment: with @Manish answer you also need java `JDK 7` for `android-21`.

Answer (score 1):

Set your project target to `target=android-21`